# HTML Border Alignment

Tags: html, css

I want the second border frame exactly below the telephone image, like the one below Gmail. I don't know what I am doing wrong but I am unable to align it. Would really appreciate the help:)

```css
.b1 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.464);
  height: 280px;
  width: 224px;
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 1.2%;
  float: left;
}

.nav {
  background-color: crimson;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="movie.html"> <img style=" margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 12px; float: left;  " src="images/back.png" width="30px" height="30px">
  </a>
  <h1 style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; font-family:Verdana; color: white; ">CineScape</h1>
</div>

<img style="height: 60px; width: 60px; margin-left: 24%; margin-top: 12%; display: inline;" src="images/gmail.png">
<img style="height: 60px; width: 60px; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 12%;   display: inline;" src="images/telephone.png">
<img style="height: 60px; width: 60px; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 12%; display: inline; " src="images/linkedin.png">
<br>
<div class="b1">
  <p style="color: white;padding-left: 9px;padding-top: 4%;  font-family: Verdana ;"><b> cinescape@gmail.com </b>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="b1">
  <p style="color: white;padding-left: 9px;padding-top: 4%;  font-family: Verdana ;"><b>042-8382999
    </b>
  </p>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaIzY.png)

Tried the code I shared above and many more stuff. But can't align it like the first border

Comment: look either in Flexbox or CSS-Grid. Also, note to only use one style tag. Since the `scope` attribute has been deprecated severely ears ago, it is no longer valid to place a style tag inside the body. It is also invalid to place visual elements into the head element. the head element is not to be mistaken with header. The head element is only for meta information about the document. All visual content belongs into the body!

Comment: PS: For the future i advice the usage of a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)

Answer (score 1):

you are giving the margin-left '%'

```
<img style="height: 60px; width: 60px; margin-left: 24%; margin-top: 12%; display: inline;" src="images/gmail.png">
```

so in diffrent width won't work correctly
you can use that instead.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cont.css"> 
        <style>
        .nav{
            background-color: crimson;
            height: 60px;
            display: flex; 
        }
        p {
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.464);
            height: 280px;
            width: 224px;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top:1.2%;
            gap:40px;
        }
        .b1 {
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:column;
            align-items: center;
        }
        b {
            color:black;
        }
       </style>
       <div class="nav">
       <a href="movie.html" > <img style=" margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 12px; float: left;  " src="images/back.png" width="30px" height="30px" >  
       </a>
       <h1 style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; font-family:Verdana; color: white; "  >CineScape</h1>
       </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="b1">
            <img style="height: 60px; width: 60px;" src="images/gmail.png">
            <p style="color: white;padding-left: 9px;padding-top: 4%;  font-family: Verdana ;">
                <b> cinescape@gmail.com </b>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="b1">
            <img style="height: 60px; width: 60px;" src="images/telephone.png">
            <p style="color: white;padding-left: 9px;padding-top: 4%;  font-family: Verdana ;">
                <b> 042-8382999 </b>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="b1">
            <img style="height: 60px; width: 60px;" src="images/linkedin.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```